# Type-hinting classes belonging to the same interface

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

Code:

```py
import abc


class Interface(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    @classmethod
    def make(cls): ...

class AObject(Interface):
    def __init__(self, a: int):
        self.a = a

    @classmethod
    def make(cls):
        return cls(a=3)

class BObject(Interface):
    def __init__(self, b: int):
        self.b = b

    @classmethod
    def make(cls):
        return cls(b=3)


data: tuple[Interface, ...] = (AObject, BObject) # Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Tuple[Type[AObject], Type[BObject]]", variable has type "Tuple[Interface, ...]")  [assignment]
```

There is an interface that implements classes and we need to specify that the classmethod `make` exists for the class. But if you specify the type `tuple[Interface, ...]`, MyPy will return an error, because you can specify the type only for class  instances, and not for the classes themselves

So, the question is — how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your problem, but if you want to specify that a variable stores a class of some sort you can use [`typing.Type`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kinds_of_types.html#the-type-of-class-objects):

```py
import abc
from typing import Tuple, Type
...
data: Tuple[Type[Interface], Type[Interface]] = (AObject, BObject)  # mypy is happy
```

Comment: And in python >=3.9, you can parametrise the builtin `type` function directly.